# Front shift cable clip (?) loose, where does it go?

Tags: shifter

On my 2021 Trek Domane SL5, the shift cable started to dangle freely a few days ago. It comes with what looks like a clip that's attached to it.

I'm not quite sure where that clip is supposed to go. It doesn't really seem to fit well anywhere on the derailleur assembly.

Where can I find a handbook or specification for how to attach the clip correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be the Link Cover?

[image]
[image]
[Diagram](https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-FD-R7000-4332C.pdf)

It has to be the last part the cable goes through.

Found a clearer picture - shows full cable routing
[image]
[Dealer's Manual](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/RAFD001/DM-RAFD001-05-ENG.pdf)

Comment: That seems to be the right answer, thanks! Brief follow-up question though. Depending on what gear I'm in, and how far I push the cable through the hole in the cover, it seems to rub either on my frame or the crank arm. Is this fine/expected, or should I resolve this somehow? Rubbing frame: https://photos.app.goo.gl/KxPYabqWE6PHneuJ7 ; rubbing crank: https://photos.app.goo.gl/hzx9XMGyMQiorA9s8

Comment: Adjacent question -- where does one find the kind of schematic you shared? Is that published by Trek/Shimano?

Comment: @TimoStaudinger Sorry, I should have included the links - I added them to my answer.

Comment: Ah, once routed correctly, the cable is no longer rubbing. Much appreciated!